# Why an extra `CMP` command are needed to implement test-and-set(TSL)?

Tags: multithreading, assembly, operating-system, thread-safety, locking

The following codes are from Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set)

```
enter_region:        ; A "jump to" tag; function entry point.

  tsl reg, flag      ; Test and Set Lock; flag is the
                     ; shared variable; it is copied
                     ; into the register reg and flag
                     ; then atomically set to 1.

  cmp reg, #0        ; Was flag zero on entry_region?

  jnz enter_region   ; Jump to enter_region if
                     ; reg is non-zero; i.e.,
                     ; flag was non-zero on entry.

  ret                ; Exit; i.e., flag was zero on
                     ; entry. If we get here, tsl
                     ; will have set it non-zero; thus,
                     ; we have claimed the resource as-
                     ; sociated with flag.

leave_region:
  move flag, #0      ;store 0 in flag
  ret                ;return to caller
```

As I understand these 2 commands `tsl reg, flag` and `cmp reg, #0` can just merge into one command `tsl reg, flag`, which does three things together: (1) copy `flag` into `reg` (2) set `flag` to `1` (3)  test whether `reg` is zero. What is the benefit or the necessarity to seperate the `(3)` from `tsl` command? Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 0):

`tsl` does not actually test the contents of `flag` (besides its name); it justs copies `flag` to `reg` atomically. In x86 it is usually implemented with the `xchg` or compare-and-swap instructions, when the latter are avaliable.